# Classification-Problem based on limited Dataset (Need keywords to search/ reading recommendations)

Tags: classification, regression, predictive-modeling

I have a dataset of about **200 test subjects**, each with **age**, **testscore** and a **one of two possible traits**. I want to define some kind of **function**, where I input age and testscore, **that predicts which of the two traits they have as good as possible**, based on the limited dataset. Or a reasonable approximation at least, a human readable function that is not 100% optimal would be preferable.

To me it seems like some kind of regression, as I want to minimize the error between the prediction and the actual dataset. But the way it's done at the moment goes something like:

```
If Testscore > 10 -> Trait A;
Else If Testscore > 9 and Age < 8 -> Trait A; 
Else If Testscore < 3 -> Disqualify; 
else -> Trait B;
```

Mind you, this is the result of trial and error in excel, so everything about this can theoretically go. But I have this problem, where I don't know what keywords I need to search in order to solve the problem. Recommendations Welcome!

Comment: The [`imodels` package](https://github.com/csinva/imodels) might be of interest to you, as it can create interpretable models with the same structure that you have now created manually.

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising!